# Present login screen with notification center when app enters background and foreground, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, appdelegate

I have Login screen and I would like to present it or just add it to navigation, it doesn't matter right now, still not sure which way I would like it to be, everytime my app comes back to foreground. Code below partially works, it does start face id, but actually whole login screen isn't shown, I can still see my last screen that was opened before entering background. I would like to hide everything with login screen. When I print childrens in appMovedToBackground function, correct view controller is printed, which means its added, but as I said, its not showing, only icon from face id can be seen. Code below is on one view controller only, currently, I would like this to be applied to all my view controllers, should I move functionality to appdelegate? Thanks in advance.

```
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appCameToForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("its in background")
    let authVC = AuthViewController()
    navigationController?.topViewController?.addChild(authVC)
}

@objc func appCameToForeground() {
    print("app enters foreground")
    if let authVC = navigationController?.topViewController?.children.first as? AuthViewController {
    print("willEnterForegroundNotification")
        authVC.checkBiometricsAndStart()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to correctly add the vc

```
@objc func appMovedToBackground() {
   print("its in background")
   guard let added = navigationController?.topViewController else { return } 
   let authVC = AuthViewController()
   authVC.view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
   added.view.addSubview(authVC.view)
   added.addChild(authVC)
}
```

Regarding that you need it for all vcs , yes implementing it inside AppDelegate is the easiest way

Comment: thanks, this did help, one more question. since same loginVC is set as root and I would like it to be shown when app enters foreground, in loginVC in viewDidLoad I always call function for face id, and now, since it is in viewDidLoad, when app goes to background it immediately  starts faceId. What should I change so faceId actually starts when I open app again, not when loginVC is added to stack. @Sh_Khan

Comment: Don't call it in `viewDidLoad` call it inside `appCameToForeground`